# Node.js database mutex between clustered processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Currently I am working on a web app which backend is made on Nodejs with MongoDB and mongoose as ORM.

When running on production, the app is clustered so we can take advantage of the multi-core machine that is running on.

We have a method on an endpoint of the API that checks for a flag in database and if it is not set we write this flag so the method is never executed again.

My question is, what if two users fires this method at the same time and one user is handled by one "cluster" and the other handled by other "cluster"? Will this situation come into a race-condition and find ourselves in an inconsistent state?

This app will handle many concurrent users so it is likely this could happen.

I'm sure this doesn't happen on a non-clustered environment because V8 runs on single-loop, but what about clustered environments?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will this situation come into a race-condition and find ourselves in an inconsistent state?

Yes, this is a race condition. As for the inconsistent states: if all those guys do is set a flag then this is an atomic operation anyway (or is it?), so you can't end up in an inconsistent state. But for any non-atomic operation that would be bad.

One way to handle this situation is to use locks. Googling "nodejs distributed lock" gives few interesting libraries.

Comment: MongoDB is atomic on single-document operations. What I suppose on this is that if I try to read a document that is currently being updated, the event loop will wait for the update operation to read it. This is OK for me. Maybe what I have to do is update the document at the top of my function and then check for the flag instead of checking first and updating then. Maybe I am not explaining too well myself.

Comment: @Jorge Changing the order doesn't matter, the race condition is still there, just in reversed order. If the update is atomic then you don't have to do any locks, you are fine because it is impossible to read an intermediate value (by the definition of atomicity). It also shouldn't matter if multiple clients do update, right? It's just one-time query per process (if I understand correctly). In case of more complex operations you may want to use `upsert` flag on insert and/or use `findAndModify`. In proper database (yes, mongo is not a proper database) you simply use transactions.

Comment: Perfect @freakish! Thank you very much :)